# How to add quotes to jq output to create a secret to kubectl secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, kubectl

```
kubectl -n aqua123 create secret generic aquadocker1234 --from-env-file=<(
    aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id aqua_secret |
    jq -r '.SecretString' | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | '.key' + "=" + '.value'')
```

The output of the jq script is in the form of `xyz123@gmail.com= password1234`. The Kubernates Secret is not liking the @ sign in output.I want the output like `'xyz123@gmail.com'= 'password1234'` (with quotes).

How can I modify my jq code to get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using single quotes for your filter, but don't do anything to escape the inner single quotes. You need to do proper escaping to have those single quotes.  Within a single quoted string, you would have to close the single quotes, switch to double quotes to add the single quote, then change back.  i.e., `'"'"'`

```
... jq -r '.SecretString | to_entries[] | "'"'"'\(.key)'"'"'='"'"'\(.value)'"'"'"'
```

If you find yourself needing single quotes frequently, it might be beneficial for you to define some functions in your `.jq` file.

```
def squot: "'";
def squot($val): "\(squot)\($val|gsub(squot; "\\\(squot)"))\(squot)";
```

With this, your filter now becomes:

```
... jq -r '.SecretString | to_entries[] | "\(squot(.key))=\(squot(.value))"'
```

Comment: I have to modify little to get the correct output ....                                                           
jq -r '.SecretString' | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "'"'"'\(.key)'"'"'='"'"'\(.value)'"'"'"'

Answer (score 8):

This is a job for jq's `@sh`.  Consider:

```
jq -rn '{"key": "xyz123@gmail.com", "value": "password1234"}
  | "\(.key|@sh)=\(.value|@sh)" '
```

#### Output

```
'xyz123@gmail.com'='password1234'
```

Comment: Dude. You rock. Hardcore